# Trigger event when AsyncTask is complete using Listener

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listener

I'm having some confusion on how to use Listeners to pass information between classes and activities.

The scenario is this:
I have a task that reads data from an Sqlite database and puts this data into an ArrayList that is passed to an Adapter which then displays it on the screen.

The question:
My app crashes when i attempt to update the listener interface with a value. It doesnt show anything in the logcat...it just hangs the app.
Could someone kindly point out where i'm going wrong. - Thanks

Details:
I have the database processing done by a class called DatbaseRoutines and within it an inner method doing the heavy lifting. the method is using AsyncTask so as not to hog the main thread.

I have created and Interface with a single method

```
 public interface DatabaseProcessListener {
  public void ProcessingIsDone(boolean blnProcessIsFinished);
}
```

In my DatabaseRoutines class i am creating a private variable

```
private DatabaseProcessListener dbProcesslistener;
```

along with a setter for it

```
   public void setDbProcesslistener(DatabaseProcessListener dbProcesslistener) {
    this.dbProcesslistener = dbProcesslistener;
    }
```

When processing is done, i use the PostExecute method to update the Listener so that this can change the value in the listener to True (ie that db processing is done)
below is the code

```
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
                dialog.dismiss(); //i have progress dialog during processing and its                        
                //closed here

                if (blnUpdateSucceededStatus) 
                 {
                     dbProcesslistener.ProcessingIsDone(true);
                  } 
                   else 
                  {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Transactions Processing   
                     failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   } ;
```

Finally in the activity displaying the data gathered from the database I Implement the listener. see below.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DatabaseProcessListener 
{

@Override
public void ProcessingIsDone(boolean blnProcessIsFinished) {
    if(blnProcessIsFinished){
        PopulateExpandableListView();
    }
   public void PopulateExpandableListView() {
   //code for populating the listview goes here;
     }
}
```

after some digging i found the logcat error..its a nullpointer exception

```
05-05 11:11:18.590: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.mledger.DatabaseRoutines$1.onPostExecute(DatabaseRoutines.java:258)
    at com.example.mledger.DatabaseRoutines$1.onPostExecute(DatabaseRoutines.java:141)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Unfortunately the app is hanging and the interface never updates the Activity that displays data with true (ie processing is done)

Do point me in the right direction.  - Thanks

Comment: Did you check if onPostExecute() got called for your AsyncTask.

Comment: Yes I did. I put a breakpoint and it just freezes on the line calling the listener. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the Answer! I was not initializing the listener in my calling class. all i needed to do was put in this line

```
db.setDbProcesslistener(this);
```

ie

```
DatabaseRoutines db = new DatabaseRoutines(MyActivity.this);
db.setDbProcesslistener(MyActivity.this);
```

and it started working.

Thanks to everyone who had a look and tried to think of the solution :)

Comment: @KuriaNdungu--THANK YOU for posting what DID work. Thank you ALSO for the FINE JOB of showing enough of your code that EVERYBODY now can try to apply this technique.

Comment: AH, MAN!!!!!! All I did was thoughtfully cut and paste the first 3 and 5th hunks of @Kuria's code into my app and modified my own `onPostExecute` to have one line--`dbProcesslistener.ProcessingIsDone(true);` and then I got NPE, so I woke up and pasted in his line to suit my `app`: `dbc.setDbProcesslistener(this);` AND IT WORKED. STUDY THIS EXAMPLE of a VERY important technique. SUPER JOB, Kuria!! This is exemplary SO Q and (USER'S!) working A!

Comment: @DSlomer64 1) star the question 2) upvote erythang 3) start a bounty and give it to Kuria.

Comment: @Will--I did star the question yesterday (as a favorite, yes?) and upvoted all but one (and just did it, too) but I don't know what you mean by `start a bounty and **give it to Kuria**`. I hovered over "start a bounty" and it looks like I'd lose rep maybe, which isn't life and death, but ... I've never done a bounty (obviously). Moreover, start bounty says "offer rep for better answers". I don't think there could be a better answer than what we have here. So I'm really confused and/or missing something. Not resisting, just confused. How would I "give it to Kuria"?

Comment: I just read this: `What is a bounty? How can I start one? If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.` This doesn't fall into that category, does it? I LOVE what I found here. It's exemplary. So I don't see giving 50 rep out of 900 for this. Am I still missing point?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the `dbProcesslistener` variable is `NULL`. Do you call your setter and pass it an initialized Listener object some time before you invoke `dbProcesslistener.ProcessingIsDone(true);`?

Comment: Thanks. that was actually the problem. i wasn't initializing before invoking.